# Identify field-separator-character as non-filed-separator in Awk

Tags: awk

Input file : Input.csv

```
3,555-912421,gg
2,555-812471,gg
4,555-821411,mmkiki
1,555-818811,fgh
sfesg gags
gsag,g gash srghsrhg
gwhg|ghsesa|gg
```

In this file, the filed separator is the comma ",". I want to print all those lines from this file which does not have the comma as field separator so,

Output:

```
sfesg gags
gsag,g gash srghsrhg
gwhg|ghsesa|gg
```

notice that 6th line in the input is part of output because a comma in the first string "gsag,g"  is part the string, not a field separator. So basically the input file can have a field separator character (comma in this case ) as a part of a word or a string, in which case line containing the field separator character it should be printed in the output.

Comment: unclear and you have to add your own efforts(the current screenshot is from an answer you got in this thread)... how would you distinguish that `,` is part of field data and not field separator? for given sample, one could print all lines not containing two commas.. would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner work for given example:

```
awk '/[[:space:]]/||!/,/' file
```

Comment: ,it gives an extra line in the output  `1,555-818811,fgh
`

Comment: @Vicky no, it won't, copy and paste my command. or checking if the line has trailing spaces.

Comment: "@Kent", please refer attached image

Comment: @Vicky check the 555-81... line, if it contains trailing space.

Comment: "@Kent" , that works now , but I was looking for something that involved IFS in the solution. I will accept it as a solution though. But if I added a line that has only , and "|" . wouldn't this command fail ?

Comment: @Vicky don't know what do you want. this does exactly what you expected in question description.

Comment: "@Kent", I added one more line in the end in the input file `ghg|hh,gf|kkl` and it appears in the output after running your command but I am not sure how . Would you be able to guide me here ?

Comment: oh my mistake , I added a trailing space again in `ghg|hh,gf|kkl`. But if this line was in the input how do I get it in the output ?

Comment: "@RavinderSingh13, My requirement is not changed , I just tweaked the input to check the command if it works for all types of input .

Comment: @Vicky first you should define a rule of "separator"  like `a,b|c,d|ef` who knows `|` or `,` should be the separator?  anyway, to break an answer by playing around the unclear input pattern is an easy thing. good luck.

Comment: "@Kent, not trying to break the answer, as stated earlier in my comment I am accepting this as a solution. I was trying to improve my own understanding. I figured that if  I include all the character that are not separators in the search pattern I can get through this, like `awk '/[[:space:]]/||!/,/ || !/|/'` when one more line `ghg|hh,gf|kkl` is included. Thanks.

Comment: @Vicky as I commented, I don't know, you tell me `555-foo,bar-blah` is CSV or `-`SV ?